# Calculating first and follow sets of this grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

I am doing exam questions for compilers. The question is to find the first and follow sets of the following grammar:

```
S → uBDz
B → Bv | w
D → EF
E → y | e
F → x | e
```

This is what I got when I calculated the First set:

```
First
S  u,v,w,y,x,z,e
B  v,w
D  y,x,e
E  y,e
F  x,e
```

My lecturer already did a solution but I can't seem to understand where he got the answer:

```
   First     Follow
S  u         $
B  w         y,x,z,y
D  y,x,e     z
E  y,e       x,z
F  x,e       z
```

PS. e = epsilon

PSS. this is the example I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDoo5BF9T4E&t=787s

Comment: I think there is a typo here. The follow set for `B` should be `v`, `x`, `y`, `z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A symbol is in the FIRST set of a non-terminal if the expansion of that non-terminal can start with that symbol. That's the definition of a FIRST set, and if your algorithm does not produce that result, the algorithm is wrong.

For example, the only production for `S` in your example grammar is:

```
S → uBDz
```

That means that every expansion of `S` must start with `u`. There is no way to get around that fact. It's impossible to skip over the `u` and continue the production with some other string. So it's easy to see that FIRST(S) is precisely `{u}`.

Similarly, `B` has two productions

```
B → Bv
B → w
```

That means that `B` can produce:

```
w
Bv → wv
Bv → Bvv → wvv
Bv → Bvvv → wvvv
```

and so on. The expansions can contain as many `v` as you want, but the first symbol is always `w`. So FIRST(B) is precisely `{w}`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Do you mind explaining how I could also get the follow sets please